# pg_dump from one docker container to other

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker

I have a node app running in a container and need to run pg_dump to a container running postgres.
I have install postgres client on node container and configure .pgpass so postgres dont ask for password.

The problem is that if i run the command from the console inside the node container the backup is done, but when i try to do it with spawn i recieve proccess exit with code 1.

**Command in the console that works fine**

```
 pg_dump -h postgres -U lims -d lims -f ./db_backup.sql
```

**Command with spawn, exits with code 1**

```
    const backupProcess = spawn('pg_dump', ['-c', '-h postgres -U lims -d lims -f ./db_backup.sql '])

//postgres is the name on docker network for the postgres container. I have tried replacing it with the container ip.
```

What am i missing?

Is there a way to see child process error?

I am already listening to child`s 'exit' and 'error' events but always exit emits.

Comment: `spawn('pg_dump', ['-h', 'postgres', '-U', 'lims', '-d', 'lims', '-f', './db_backup.sql'])` > by not splitting your arguments in an array, I suspect they get misinterpreted.

Comment: Thank you... The problem was that passing the arguments as a string with -c wasnt working. I suppose that maybe because the terminal is not bash but sh. And when i was passing the arguments as array y wasnt spliting the flag from the value. ex: '-h postgres'